# RuntimeError: NoSectionError: No section: 'ceph-source'

Tags: ceph

When I use `ceph-deploy` to install the ceph to every node:

```
ceph-deploy install node0 node1 node2
```

I get the below error:

```
[node1][WARNIN] check_obsoletes has been enabled for Yum priorities plugin
[node1][INFO  ] Running command: rpm --import https://download.ceph.com/keys/release.asc
[node1][INFO  ] Running command: rpm -Uvh --replacepkgs https://download.ceph.com/rpm-jewel/el7/noarch/ceph-release-1-0.el7.noarch.rpm
[node1][DEBUG ] Retrieving https://download.ceph.com/rpm-jewel/el7/noarch/ceph-release-1-0.el7.noarch.rpm
[node1][DEBUG ] Preparing...                          ########################################
[node1][DEBUG ] Updating / installing...
[node1][WARNIN] warning: /etc/yum.repos.d/ceph.repo created as /etc/yum.repos.d/ceph.repo.rpmnew
[node1][DEBUG ] ceph-release-1-1.el7                  ########################################
[node1][WARNIN] ensuring that /etc/yum.repos.d/ceph.repo contains a high priority
[ceph_deploy][ERROR ] RuntimeError: NoSectionError: No section: 'ceph-source'
```

---

**EDIT**

I have tried remove the ceph-release:

```
yum remove ceph-release
```

But useless.

Answer (score 0):

From the error, you should know there is no section for ceph-source in the `ceph.conf` file.

Try to add the below code to the `ceph.conf`:

```
[ceph-source]
name=Ceph source packages
baseurl=http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ceph/rpm-infernalis/el7/SRPMS
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
type=rpm-md
gpgkey=http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ceph/keys/release.asc
priority=1
```

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me while installing ceph on CentOS 7.

I followed the solution on the Ceph Bug Tracker:
http://tracker.ceph.com/issues/12694

Just move the ceph yum repo in each node as bellow:

```
sudo mv /etc/yum.repos.d/ceph.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/ceph-deploy.repo
```

Then retry installing the nodes.